# making header row the width of the data row in html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a table in HTML. The problem is that I have set space between each cell so I used margin for that. but that causes that I can not have `col-12` for a row, so in this case, it became `col-11`(sum of all cols). but it caused the row header to be in a full row and iterative rows (data row) are not in a full row. how can I make the header row be in data row width?

[image]

```css
.event-col {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.event-col-header {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0px !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: IRANSans;
}

.event-row {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #c1d2fe;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <table id="example" class="table dt-responsive nowrap showborder ">
      <tr class="event-row mb-1">
        <th class="col-1 event-col-header">No</th>
        <th class="col-2 event-col-header">Name </th>
        <th class="col-1 event-col-header">Date</th>
        <th class="col-2 event-col-header">Hour</th>
        <th class="col-5 event-col-header">Address</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="col-1 event-col">@counter</td>
        <td class="col-2 event-col">@item.Name</td>
        <td class="col-1 event-col">@item.EventDate</td>
        <td class="col-2 event-col"> @item.StartTime </td>
        <td class="col-5 event-col">@item.Address</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your code as follows:

```css
.event-col {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #fff;
    /*padding: 10px;*/
    /*margin: 2px;*/
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.event-col-header {
    /*padding: 10px;*/
    /*margin: 2px;*/
    display: inline-block;
    /*border: 0 !important;*/
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: IRANSans;
}
.event-row {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #c1d2fe;
    /*margin: 10px;*/
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <!-- bootstrap 4.6 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- my style-sheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row text-right">
    <div class="col-11 mx-auto">
        <table id="example" class="table table-borderless table-responsive" >
            <tr class="event-row mb-1">
                <th class="col-1">
                    <span class="event-col-header">No</span>
                </th>
                <th class="col-2">
                    <span class="event-col-header">Name</span>
                </th>
                <th class="col-1">
                    <span class="event-col-header">Date</span>
                </th>
                <th class="col-2">
                    <span class="event-col-header">Hour</span>
                </th>
                <th class="col-5">
                    <span class="event-col-header">Address</span>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td class="col-1">
                    <span class="event-col p-3">@counter</span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-2">
                    <span class="event-col p-3">@item.Name</span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-1">
                    <span class="event-col p-3">@item.EventDate</span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-2">
                    <span class="event-col p-3">@item.StartTime</span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-5">
                    <span class="event-col p-3">@item.Address</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td class="col-1">
                    <span class="event-col p-3">@counter</span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-2">
                    <span class="event-col p-3">@item.Name</span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-1">
                    <span class="event-col p-3">@item.EventDate</span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-2">
                    <span class="event-col p-3">@item.StartTime</span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-5">
                    <span class="event-col p-3">@item.Address</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td class="col-1">
                    <span class="event-col p-3">@counter</span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-2">
                    <span class="event-col p-3">@item.Name</span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-1">
                    <span class="event-col p-3">@item.EventDate</span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-2">
                    <span class="event-col p-3">@item.StartTime</span>
                </td>
                <td class="col-5">
                    <span class="event-col p-3">@item.Address</span>
                </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<!-- bootstrap scripts -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

> Important tips in **my opinion** about that code:

1- Do not put your text directly inside a `col-1` or `col-2` or ... . suppose them as **container** and put contents inside other HTML tags like `<span>` in this example.

2- Use [margin and padding utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/) of bootstrap instead of setting margin and padding yourself.

3- When you use `row` and `col-*` classes, usually using `container-fluid` or `container` classes gives better results. So I put a `.container-fluid` tag as a whole parent for table.

4- If you want to support responsiveness in your table, bootstrap has a [.table-responsive](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/content/tables/#responsive-tables) class that you can add to your table.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same width but since you are using inline-block they not use total of parent elemment
and so you are not using bootstrap cols correctly
for in tables you no need to use cols and rows

bootstrap gird system is not good for tables
try to build it without BS gird

Answer (score 0):

When I see the [bootstrap table](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/content/tables/) documentation, I could not find any example that uses `col-*` classes inside tables. So I also wrote another code that uses HTML `<colgroup>` tag instead of using `col-*` classes that has similar result:

```css
.event-col {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
.event-col-header {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: IRANSans;
}
.event-row {
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #c1d2fe;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <!-- bootstrap 4.6 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- my style-sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body dir="rtl">

<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row text-right">
  <div class="col-11 mx-auto">
    <table id="example" class="table table-borderless table-responsive" >
      <colgroup>
        <col style="width: 9%">
        <col style="width: 18%">
        <col style="width: 9%">
        <col style="width: 18%">
        <col style="width: 46%">
      </colgroup>
      <tr class="event-row mb-1">
        <th>
          <span class="event-col-header">No</span>
        </th>
        <th>
          <span class="event-col-header">Name</span>
        </th>
        <th>
          <span class="event-col-header">Date</span>
        </th>
        <th>
          <span class="event-col-header">Hour</span>
        </th>
        <th>
          <span class="event-col-header">Address</span>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td>
          <span class="event-col p-3">@counter</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="event-col p-3">@item.Name</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="event-col p-3">@item.EventDate</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="event-col p-3">@item.StartTime</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="event-col p-3">@item.Address</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td>
          <span class="event-col p-3">@counter</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="event-col p-3">@item.Name</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="event-col p-3">@item.EventDate</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="event-col p-3">@item.StartTime</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="event-col p-3">@item.Address</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr >
        <td>
          <span class="event-col p-3">@counter</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="event-col p-3">@item.Name</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="event-col p-3">@item.EventDate</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="event-col p-3">@item.StartTime</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span class="event-col p-3">@item.Address</span>
        </td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- bootstrap scripts -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to tangle Bootstrap's grid layout with tables. If all you're after is the bubble styling, put divs inside your table cells and use those.

If you then want to size some columns explicitly, do that.

```css
.event-row {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #c1d2fe;
}

.event-col {
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.event-col-header {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 0px !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: IRANSans;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <table id="example" class="table dt-responsive nowrap showborder">
      <tr class="event-row mb-1">
        <th>
          <div class="event-col-header">No</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="event-col-header">Name</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="event-col-header">Date</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="event-col-header">Hour</div>
        </th>
        <th>
          <div class="event-col-header">Address</div>
        </th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="event-col">@counter</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="event-col">@item.Name</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="event-col">@item.EventDate</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="event-col"> @item.StartTime</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div class="event-col">@item.Address</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```